# How to send data map to a web service?

Tags: java, rest, dictionary

I've got this code of my web service:

```
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static Response fillData(final Map<String, Object> data) {  
       ...  
       final byte[] file = ...
       return Response.ok(file).build();
```

How do I send the Map data to the service?

```
final javax.ws.rs.core.Response reponse = client.target(URL_REST).path("/path").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(?);
```

Here is a sample of my JSON file:

```
{
  "activity" : {
    "code" : "ACT_014",
    "title" : "FIGHTING"
  },
  "adress" : {
    "place" : "",
    "number" : ""
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can the value of `data` really be any `Object`? Could you please show a sample JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE:

```
.post(Entity.entity(data, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE), Response.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried via HttpURLConnection?

```
URL url = new URL(URL_REST);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        String input = "{\"activity\" :....}";

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();
```

... and collect output response data

Answer (score 0):

U can also use postman, curl or soapUI if U know host adress.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't requirements for the technology of the client side, you can use the Restlet framework and the library `org.json`. Here is below a sample of code:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://...");
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("activity", "my value");
(...)
cr.post(new JsonRepresentation(obj));
```

Hope it helps,
Thierry